# clearing linebreaks from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to remove linebreaks when posting from word in a textarea. Atm this isnt working at all, eventhou i thought this should be a breeze. I'm sure i'm forgetting something small but i cant figure it out. This is the method that gets called on paste.

```
function cleanLineBreaks(el) {
    var editedText = $(el).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
    $(el).val(editedText);
}
```

I created a fiddle to explain.

Just paste some text that has linebreaks in it, as you can see, the linebreaks arent cleaned

https://jsfiddle.net/gg56rw36/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass current object to `cleanLineBreaks` function.

Also, you need to bind `onPaste` event handler, not `onclick`.

```
<textarea onclick="cleanLineBreaks(this)"></textarea>
```

```js
function cleanLineBreaks(el) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var editedText = $(el).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
        $(el).val(editedText);
    },0);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea onPaste="cleanLineBreaks(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry, i havent explained my problem very well. I meant i wanted to remove the breaks on paste. I updated my jsfiddle so the function gets triggered on paste.